# Loading external data into Ember template using ember-data/DataStore

Tags: ajax, json, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

Here is what I'm tyrnig to do:

1. Make ajax request to retrieve JSON data from a PHP script
2. Insert that information into DataStore Models
3. Store those models within a controller
4. Display the information using {{#each}} with a handlebars template

---

- Does ember-data have a built in way of retrieving data? If not, where
  should the AJAX request be implemented?
- What is the best way to insert the JSON data into the DS model?
- What is the best way to then sync the models up with a Controller?

---

Any examples that implement all of the 4 steps would also be very helpful, since I can't seem to find any.

Comment: external data as in data from an API in another domain or simply retrieve data from your own backend API? either way you should be able to extend your `DS.Store` to implement an `Adapter` that can consume whichever API. You might have to extend the `Adapter`'s `Serializer` as well. It allows you to extend a lot of things without throwing away several good features. But I'm under the impression that most of these questions have already been answered individually in StackOverflow. Look it up

Comment: The problem with other the other answers on SO is that there is a lot of inconsistency. A lot of answers are for older version of Ember or too specific to be helpful. Anyway, it gets confusing.

I am going to use my own backend. I think I will use the RESTAdapter.

Comment: This question asks a lot of things at the same time, and any answer will give you a lot to absorb, so I strongly recommend going through the [**guides**](http://emberjs.com/guides/) and getting the [**Ember screencast from PeepCode**](https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**<edit>**

Like I said in the comments, this questions asks a lot at once, so to follow up, here's a work in progress fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/dWcUp/

This is not 100%, but covers some of your questions. It uses the FixtureAdapter.
I'll be updating it as I find time.

**</edit>**

> 1 Make ajax request to retrieve JSON data from a PHP script

Ember-Data will take care of that for you. Consider the following:

```
window.App = Em.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    imageUrl: DS.attr('string')
})
```

The code above defines a data store (almost like an ORM) within your client app. Ember uses convention over configuration (heavily), so as per configuration this code expects your backend to have a resource in the same domain as `/products` which talks to GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.

> 2 Insert that information into DataStore Models

Considering what I said above, by calling one of the following:

`App.store.find(App.Product)` or `App.Product.find()`

EmberData will fire a GET request through AJAX targeting your resource `/products`, and if you say `App.Product.find(1)`, it will target `/products/1`. 
Your app `store` will use its `adapter` and the adapter's `serializer` to translate the JSON result and materialize its data into your `App.Product` model.

> 3 Store those models within a controller

This is done when defining your application router. Regardless of what you do, Ember will run its own workflow, but it provides you several hooks, giving you the control of that specific action. Consider the following:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('products');
});

App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Product.find();
  }
});
```

The code above populates the model used in the `products` route (which you would access at http://yourdomain.com/#/products). Internally it will generate the code for your `ProductsController`, or you can define your own, which should extend `ArrayController`. 
Controllers will have a `content` property which is an alias to the model or model collection. Again, convention over configuration.

> 4 Display the information using {{#each}} with a handlebars template

Providing you're following the conventions, in your handlebars template, you should iterate through your collection like this:

```
{{#each product in controller}}
    {{#linkTo 'product' product}}
        {{product.name}}
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

---

> - Does ember-data have a built in way of retrieving data? If not, where
>     should the AJAX request be implemented?

Yes, simply call `App.Product.find()` for a product model and it return you a blank `ModelArray` while firing the AJAX request to the products resource in your backend, then materialize/populate your data into each model once it receives the data back from the server.

> - What is the best way to insert the JSON data into the DS model?

You shouldn't be concerned about this if you're using ember-data. The framework does that for you in most cases. That's why we love it. You might, however, have to configure mapping, namespace and plurals depending on your backend.

> - What is the best way to then sync the models up with a Controller?

Something similar to this:

```
var product = App.Product.createRecord({
    name: 'laptop',
    imageUrl: 'path/to/image.png'
});
product.save();
```

This should fire a `POST` or `PUT` request to your backend API.

---

You should definitely check:

http://emberjs.com/guides/

https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs

http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/01/03/Intro-to-ember-js-and-the-new-router-api/

Comment: Great answer! This is more useful and concise than 99% of the information I've seen on Ember. I've already read through most of the guides on the Ember site. They do a decent job of describing each major feature, but there is little info on how to link everything together.

Answer (score 2):

**Making the AJAX request**

```
// Find all pets.
var pets = App.Pet.find();

// Find pet with ID of 1.
var pet = App.Pet.find(1);
```

**Into DataStore Models**

`pets` above will be a DS.RecordArray containing many `App.Pet` models, whereas `pet` is just one `App.Pet`.

**Store in Controller**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
       return App.Pet.find(4);
   } 
});
```

The router is used to setup the controller, and so we specify here that the `IndexController` should hold one `App.Pet` with the ID of 4. This can of course be dynamic. Since your controller represents only one model, it should be of the type `ObjectController`, but if it was used to store **many** pets, then it should be of the type `ArrayController`.

By specify the model, you will have access to it in your `IndexController` and index view (`data-template-name="index"`). This is because when you move into your index route, the `IndexController` is located/instantiated, `IndexView` is instantiated and placed into the DOM, all after consulting the `IndexRoute` for setting up the controller.

You can now do something like this in your template (although `model.` is not necessary): `{{model.name}}`, which will get you your pet's name.

**Display using #each**

Find all your pets using a modified version of the above code, but returning all of the pets. Remember, this is done by specifying no arguments to your `find` method:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
       return App.Pet.find();
   }
});
```

Now we can do loop through all of the pets in the index template. Whilst there are many ways to loop, such as including `content.`/`model.`, excluding `.content`/`model`, using `this`, `controller`, et cetera..., it's not necessary, but that's for another day. What matters at the moment is that this will work for you, and will be the most self-intuitive:

```
{{#each pet in controller}}
    {{pet.name}}
{{/each}}
```

I'll put together a jsFiddle for this if you would like. Please let me know.

**Questions**

> Does ember-data have a built in way of retrieving data? If not, where
>   should the AJAX request be implemented?

Yes, that's [Ember Data module](https://github.com/emberjs/data) which has [some good guides on EmberJS.com](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/).

> What is the best way to insert the JSON data into the DS model?

Using Ember Data as per the examples up above.

> What is the best way to then sync the models up with a Controller?

Using the `model` hook in the appropriate route to specify which model(s) your controller represents.